# How to prevent a channel from being closed when an error is encountered when calling channel.send() in a Chromecast Receiver app?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I am writing a Chromecast receiver app and I am finding that when I get an error in the channel.send() call it closes the channel and I'm not sure how I can report back an error. I would really like to be able to catch the error and report my own error such as in the code below but this isn't working out. Any suggestions?

```
try{
    channel.send({ event: 'got_cards', imCzar: false,  newCards: newCardsSet, blackCardInPlay: this.game.blackCardInPlay});
  } catch(err){
    this.sendError(channel, 'Couldn\'t retrieve cards.');
  }
```

One additional question which lead me to this first question. I am getting this failure because I am returning an empty array, is it not valid to have an empty array when sending a result back to the client?

Code to make the point: This was the initial state and in some cases no objects get added to the array.

```
var newCardsSet = [];
```

Comment: You don't mention if your channel is the standard channel, or your own, like in the tic-tac-toe app.

Comment: Sorry about that,  my channel is very much like the TicTacToe channels. I used that source as the base for the App. One thing I did puzzle out was that the channel.send() seems to fail when I pass it an array but if I first join the array into a string it would pass the data back.

Comment: Hit enter out of habit, I wanted to add that I can work with that, just wanted to let you know. The more interesting question is how can I recover when something like that happens and it seems to kill the channel? My Android app reports that the Channel was closed.